# Lebesgue measure of Borel set $Α$ such that $\mu(Α)>1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $μ$ be the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$   be a borel set such that $μ(A)> 1$. I want to show that there exist $x,y \in A$ such that $x-y \in \mathbb{Z} -\{0\} $.
If $B\subset \mathbb{R}$, we define $$B+x=\{b+x : b\in B\}$$

I need to follow these steps:

a) Show that $$μ(A)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} μ((A-n)\cap P)$$ where $P=[0,1)$

b) Show that the sets $(A-n)\cap P$ are not disjoint, and so, the sets $(A-n)$ are not disjoint. Conclude.

I already know that the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant but I don't know how to start with part a). Please help me with this.

I believe part b) follows using part a) since $((A-n)\cap P)\subset P$ so if they were disjoint, by the σ-additivity of dijoint sets and monotony we would have that $$μ(A)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} μ((A-n)\cap P)= μ(\cup (A-n)\cap P ) \leq  μ(P)=1$$ which contradicts the hypothesis that $μ(A)> 1$.

I need help with the first part so I would appreciate very much yours! Thank you!!

Comment: MathJax works in question titles as well.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$P+n$ form a partition of $\mathbb{R}$, so $A\cap (P+n)$ form a partition of $A$. Now use $\mu(A\cap (P+n) = \mu((A-n) \cap P)$

Comment: I already see it! Thank you !!

Comment: Works in more general settings: if $\mu(A)>\mu(F)$ where $F$ is a "fundamental domain" of the group $G$ then $\mu(A \cap g A) >0$ for some $g \ne e$.